# Creating custom HTML pages

Tags: plugins, html

I want to be able to create pages with just my own HTML, CSS, JS and PHP. Can this be done with plugins to still work correctly within the page?

Example: importing a WPform with a shortcode like `[wpforms id="592"]`

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There’s multiple ways this could be done but the easiest is creating templates and then assigning them to WP pages.  Have you looked at templates?  When you make templates you can just use the aspects of them that ensure they integrate with WordPress but then the content, HTML, CSS, and PHP can be entirely custom. Can be done via theme or a custom plugin too.

Comment: @TonyDjukic Thanks for this tip, I will look into templates. As an alternative, which custom plugin do you recommend for this purpose?

Comment: Sorry, I meant you could add them templates via your theme or if you can’t edit the theme you could build the custom plugin yourself to add the templates.